# Extension produces Error 404 after applying patch 5994

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, 404

After applying the patch 5994 in my magento version 1.9.1 one of my extensions began to take a 404 error message when trying to access it

See my config.xml [Pastebin Quote](http://pastebin.com/CewVFdSP)

Comment: magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 0):

This is the new security feature in full effect as outlined by Cyrill Schumacher. He also was so kind as to provide the fix: 
controller must extend admin html controller and config.xml routers section must also use admin.
If you need a custom router name, the section that needs to be added should look like this:
check blow link 
http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-routers-a-look-under-the-hood/